# How to map Time type data of FaunaDB to the go lang variable?

Tags: go, faunadb

I'm stuck on handling Time type data of faunaDB. I have no idea which type of golang is appropriate to map to Time type data of faunaDB.

I've tried the following code for fauna document creation:

```
type LabelData struct {
    RedirectURL   string `fauna:"redirectURL"`
    Owner         string `fauna:"owner"`
    RedirectCount int    `fauna:"redirectCount"`
    ExternalID    string `fauna:"externalID"`
    Tag           string `fauna:"Tag"`
    Created       int64  `fauna:created`
}

func faunaCreate(externalID string) (err error) {
    var documentRef f.RefV
    labelData := LabelData{
        RedirectURL:   "",
        Owner:         "",
        RedirectCount: 0,
        ExternalID:    externalID,
        Created:       f.ToMillis(f.Time("now")),
    }
    newlabel, err := client.Query(
        f.Create(
            f.Collection("label"),
            f.Obj{"data": labelData},
        ),
    )
```

But it occurs following error:

```
cannot use faunadb.ToMillis(faunadb.Time("now")) (type faunadb.Expr) as type int64 in field value
```

Which data type for golang should I use for faunaDB Time type? Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error is occurring coz you are trying to initialize `faunadb.Expr` type to an `int64` variable.

So you can change the type of `Created` var. Either make is `faunadb.Expr` or an `interface{}`.

```
type LabelData struct {
    RedirectURL   string `fauna:"redirectURL"`
    Owner         string `fauna:"owner"`
    RedirectCount int    `fauna:"redirectCount"`
    ExternalID    string `fauna:"externalID"`
    Tag           string `fauna:"Tag"`
    Created       interface{}  `fauna:created`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular go type `time.Time` in your struct

Comment: Hi Marrony, Thank you for your suggestion, I'm afraid that using time.Time  causes the same type of error.

Comment: You should use go types like go types, what you are trying to do is use go type and initialize with a fauna function, it won’t work.